# taking $\log$ of a function $h(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading from [*Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com.gh/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=iU4zDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (Lesson 10C page 85) and came across these steps:

> $ \frac{d\ h(x)}{h(x)} =  \frac{\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
>  P(x,y) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} Q(x,y)\bigg]}{Q(x,y)} dx \quad
>  (a)$
>
> $F(x) =   \frac{\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial y} P(x,y) -
>  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} Q(x,y)\bigg]}{Q(x,y)} \quad (b) $
>
> then $\quad log[h(x)] = \int{F(x)\ dx}$

My confusion is, if we are to substitute (b) into (a) , we will get

$$ \frac{d\ h(x)}{h(x)} = F(x)dx $$

and I know (maybe I might be wrong)

$$ F(x)dx  = \int{F(x)dx} $$

Please how did they get

$$\quad log[h(x)] = \int{F(x)\ dx}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac {dh}{h}=F(x)dx$$
Integrate both sides :
$$\int \frac {dh}{h}=\int F(x)dx$$
$$\ln |h|+C=\int F(x)dx$$
This is because the integral of $f(x)=\dfrac 1 x$ is  $\ln x$ :
$$\implies I=\int \dfrac {dx}{x}=\ln |x|+C$$

---

For example you may have this:
$$\int \frac {dx^2y^3}{x^2y^3}=\ln |x^2y^3|+C$$
Because if you substitute $A=x^2y^3$ you will have :
$$\int \frac {dA}A=\ln |A|+C=\ln |x^2y^3|+C$$

Comment: Okay. So they are representing $h(x)$ as $h$. I mean the expression can be written as $ \frac{1}{h(x)} d\ h(x) $

Comment: it's the same ...you have at the denominator what you have inside the d of $dh$ @EALehn

Comment: look at this $$\int \frac {dx^2}{x^2}=\ln |x^2|$$ @EALehn